# Automatically Bind all public properties in an Action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, model-binding, asp.net-core-2.0

In an ASP.NET (Core) Controller's Action, I bind the properties of a `ViewModel` like this

```
public async IActionResult Edit(string id,
     [Bind("Id,Name,PropA,PropB,PropC,...,PropZ,PropAA...")] RecordEditViewModel viewModel)
```

Now, every time the model changes I should remember to add the property to the Binding... Is there a way to automatically bind all public properties, without specifying it explicitly?

Comment: You have private properties in your model?

Comment: Did you try without Bind attribute? As far as I know, MVC binding looks for only public properties to bind.

Comment: no I have no particular behavior, want all public properties, it's all...

Answer (score 1):

Without Bind attribute:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, RecordEditViewModel viewModel)
```